Service vmware-sps won't start on vCenter
Consider the following VMware cluster environment:
1 x Cisco UCS 5108 Blade Server Chassis
6 x Cisco UCS B200 M3 (vSphere 6.5 Enterprise Plus)
1 x VMware vCenter Standard 6.5
We had an issue with one of the servers, probably caused by a faulty storage HBA. Unfortunately, at the time of the incident, the vCenter VM was hosted on the faulty server. We went through all kinds of troubles to manually move all the VMs to the other servers and, in the end, everything was fine except for the vCenter VM. We suspect something on it was corrupted because we are unable to get some services running, especially the vmware-sps service, which caused some problems with Veeam backups and other functionalities. When trying to manually start the vmware-sps service, we got the following:
Command> service-control --all --status
Running:
 applmgmt lwsmd pschealth vmafdd vmcad vmcam vmdird vmdnsd vmonapi vmware-cis-license vmware-cm vmware-content-library vmware-eam vmware-mbcs vmware-perfcharts vmware-psc-client vmware-rhttpproxy vmware-sca vmware-statsmonitor vmware-sts-idmd vmware-stsd vmware-updatemgr vmware-vapi-endpoint vmware-vmon vmware-vpostgres vmware-vpxd vmware-vpxd-svcs vmware-vsan-health vmware-vsm vsphere-client vsphere-ui
Stopped:
 vmware-imagebuilder vmware-netdumper vmware-rbd-watchdog vmware-sps vmware-vcha

Command> service-control --start vmware-sps
Perform start operation. vmon_profile=None, svc_names=['vmware-sps'], include_coreossvcs=False, include_leafossvcs=False
2024-08-07T12:21:32.331Z   Service sps state STOPPED
Error executing start on service sps. Details {
    "resolution": null,
    "detail": [
        {
            "args": [
                "sps"
            ],
            "id": "install.ciscommon.service.failstart",
            "localized": "An error occurred while starting service 'sps'",
            "translatable": "An error occurred while starting service '%(0)s'"
        }
    ],
    "componentKey": null,
    "problemId": null
}
Service-control failed. Error {
    "resolution": null,
    "detail": [
        {
            "args": [
                "sps"
            ],
            "id": "install.ciscommon.service.failstart",
            "localized": "An error occurred while starting service 'sps'",
            "translatable": "An error occurred while starting service '%(0)s'"
        }
    ],
    "componentKey": null,
    "problemId": null
}

/var/log/vmware/vmware-sps/sps.log
2024-08-07T09:21:36.969-03:00 [main] ERROR opId=sps-Main-33292-112 com.vmware.sps.StorageMain - Exception when running SPS service
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'httpServerEndpoint' defined in class path resource [../conf/pbm-spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'pbm.http.port' in value "${pbm.http.port}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'pbm.http.port' in value "${pbm.http.port}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:105)
        at com.vmware.vim.storage.common.app.CommonSpringService.createSpringAppContext(CommonSpringService.java:38)
        at com.vmware.pbm.app.PbmLocalService.initialize(PbmLocalService.java:135)
        at com.vmware.pbm.app.PbmLocalService.<init>(PbmLocalService.java:117)
        at com.vmware.pbm.app.PbmLocalService.initInstance(PbmLocalService.java:195)
        at com.vmware.sps.StorageMain.loadPbmService(StorageMain.java:169)
        at com.vmware.sps.StorageMain.main(StorageMain.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'pbm.http.port' in value "${pbm.http.port}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitGenericArgumentValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:159)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:220)
        ... 14 more

Our Google and official documentation searches were unsuccessful. We do not have an active VMware support contract (I know, I know, but not my fault...).
Does anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot and repair this? Thanks in advance!

Check the second line of exception, seems like you do not have variable pbm.http.port or it have unacceptable value.

In the same directory (/usr/lib/vmware-vpx/sps/conf) as the pbm.properties file, we found a very old file called pbm.properties.upgrade. This file was missing all the parameters that should have been declared in pbm.properties. I have no idea why these parameters were removed from pbm.properties, but as soon as we copied all the contents of pbm.properties.upgrade to pbm.properties, we were able to start all the services, including vmware-sps, and so far everything seems to be back to normal.
